# buy limit order is filled by matching with a sell limit order,

Tags: limit-order

When a buy limit order is filled by matching with a sell limit order, what is the manifestation of the transaction in time and sales ( buy or sell)?

Answer (score 1):

Time and sales shows volume, price, direction, date, and time data for executed trades. Since a trade involves a buy and a sell, you cannot label it one or the other.  However, some platforms will indicate if the trades are occurring at the bid, ask, or in between.

Comment: If buy limit filled my platform shows sell manifestation in footprint and if sell limit filled it shows buy thats why i was wondering if but limit filled with sell limit what happens?

Comment: Some platforms also indicate an ‘aggressor side’ (i.e. the incoming order which matched order(s) already in the order book), which can give a rough indication of whether you might want to treat the overall transaction as a buy or a sell.